# command executed in nohup is killed as soon as the putty terminal is closed

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, putty, ubuntu-10.04

I have an Amazon ubuntu ec2 instance

I'm using PuTTY to access the same.

Here, I have a large database in mysql.
I'm executing the following command to take the backup of my database.

nohup mysqldump -u username -ppassword mydatabase | gzip > mydatabase.sql.gz

Now, when I exit PuTTY, the command is no longer running in the background.

I also tried running with &

i.e
nohup mysqldump -u username -ppassword mydatabase | gzip > mydatabase.sql.gz &

All these days it was working fine.
But, all of a sudden it is behaving strangely.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

Use **screen** >> https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html

```
(starts a screen session with label "mysqlbackup")
# screen -S mysqlbackup

(Run your backup)
# mysqldump -u username -ppassword mydatabase | gzip > mydatabase.sql.gz

Ctrl+a D (this exits your screen and you can logout)

(lists all available screens)
# screen -ls

(re-attach to your mysqlbackup screen)
# screen -r mysqlbackup
```